# How to convert List<?> to List<className>

Tags: java, generics, collections

I am facing some problem when converting list to List

```
List<ContentDes> contentDes_ls  = new ArrayList<ContentDes>();
        logger.info("in getContentDes ");

        List<?> ls  = ho.getResultListByLimit(sql,limit);
        contentDes_ls = (List<ContentDes>)ls;
    logger.info(" size of content "+contentDes_ls.size());
    for (ContentDes contentDes : contentDes_ls) {
        logger.info(contentDes.getPricetag());
        logger.info(contentDes.getPrv());
    }
```

Its worked fine when I get the size of `List<SomeClass>` but when I
access the getter and setter of `SomeClass` I got exception

Output:

```
size of content 2

java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.SomeClass]
```

Comment: Generic Type can't directly do class-cast. You may iterate the List<?> by using Object, and with that, judging the class by instanceof and do class-cast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SomeClass is not mentioned anywhere in your code, so I assume you mean ContentDes.

It appears your list doesn't contain ContentDes instances. The Exception indicates the items are instead of type `Object[]`. This causes a ClassCastException when you try to iterate over the items as ContentDes.

Comment: @ marthursson : you are right.. thanx for the help 
My getResultListByLimit(sql,limit) proforms operation: 
List<?> ls_obj = session.createQuery(query).setMaxResults(limit).list();
is there any way to direct cast this result into list<ContentDes>

One method that i  know is to itrate list<Object[]> using for each loop   create object of ContentDes  and then set these value using setter method of ContentDes class and then add to the list<ContentDes>

Comment: When you cast the list from List<?> to List<ContentDes> you are basically telling the compiler "Don't worry, I'm certain that the list contains objects of this type". If they are not of this type, there is no way to magically have the system translate the objects - you will need to write explicit code for this. Now, the reason why the list doesn't contain ContentDes instances is a different question. It appears from your comment to be a Hibernate-related issue, which would be off-topic for the current question.